# DXGI flip model locked to vsync

Tags: windows, directx, windows-10, directx-11, directx-12

I found swap chain created with flip model (DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL or DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD) was locked to VSync (1/60 sec), calling IDXGISwapChain1::Present1 method with SyncInterval set to 0 as follows doesn't work.

```
swap_chain->Present1(0, 0, &param);
```

Does anyone know how to disable VSync for DXGI flip model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your version of Windows 10? UWP and windowed swap chain used to always be locked to VSync, prior to the 1511 build.

Comment: thank you so much! My previous version was 1511(OS Build 10586.713), after I upgraded it to 1607, the latest version, the problem is gone! :D

Answer (score 1):

I know this was a long time ago, but I found a solution that worked for me.

When calling `Present()` on the swap chain, you should pass `DXGI_PRESENT_ALLOW_TEARING` as a flag (second parameter).
For that to work, the swap chain requires the `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING` flag to be set.

According to Microsoft's documentation, it's used for variable refresh rate displays. I guess that makes sense (I am still very much a newbie when it comes to graphics programming).

Hope that helps!